# Indexing a 2D narray when row mask is a 1D list and column mask is a 2D list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array of zeros that looks like this:

```
stock2concept_matrix = np.zeros((3, 4))
```

I have a row mask, which is a list of indices from 0 to 2:

```
row = [0, 1, 2]
```

A column mask looks like this:

```
column = [[0, 2], [1], [0, 2, 3]]
```

I expect that

```
stock2concept_matrix[row, column] = 1
```

will change `stock2concept_matrix` to:

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

However, an error occurred:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I don't want to use a `for` loop since it's inefficient, how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.repeat` on `row` to make the right number of elements for each column entry:

```
row = np.repeat(row, [len(c) for c in column])
```

Then flatten the column list to get a pair of indices like the result of `np.where`:

```
column = [x for c in column for x in c]
```

Now you can just do

```
stock2concept_matrix[row, column] = 1
```

Numpy indices must be broadcastable together. In this case, that means that you have to have one element in each index array per element that you want to set.